# Issue with locating an element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I tried to locate an element by xpath, however, I get a syntax error:

```
"SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@aria-label data-tid = 'team-4MA 202021']' is not a valid XPath expression."
```

[This is the element I'm trying to locate](https://pastebin.pl/view/8be48233).

I tried to get find the element by class but unfortunately, there are more than 1 element with the same class.

Comment: can you share a link to the actual page and also your selenium code?